# How to print the word between the same occurence of characters

Tags: java

How would you output the word between the characters that the user inputs, for example, the input is 4(option #), `dog *is* sleeping` (phrase), *(character)
The output should be `is`. This task has to be done only using the substring method and no loops or anything else.

Here's my code:

```
else if (option == 4){
                String x = keyboard.next();
                int counter = 0;
                sub = phrase.substring(0, phrase.length());
                    if (sub == x)
                    counter++;
                    else if (counter == 1)
                        System.out.print(sub);
    }
```

I achieved this task using the for loop but now I only want to use substring method, I will show u the code using for loop so u get a better idea:

```
      else if (option == 4){
                char x = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
                int z = 0; 
                    for (int y = 0; y < phrase.length(); y++){
                        char n = phrase.charAt(y);
                            if (n == x)
                            z++;
                            else if (z == 1) 
                                System.out.print(n);
                }
            }
```

Comment: is it always 3 words? 1- dog 2- is 3-sleeping?

Comment: No it can be more

Comment: Since there is no `"*"` in the phrase `"dog is sleeping"`, why would the output be `"is"`?

Comment: I put it around is but it didn't recognize it

Comment: Can you be a little more precise ? you want to output the first word in which the last char of the first word is the same as the first char of the next word? or you want to output `"is"` because you put `dog *is* sleeping`?

Comment: Yes i want to output that

Comment: which one of the two ?

Comment: I want to output "is" because it is between the character that the user inputs through scanner

Comment: what is the character that the user inputted through the scanner in this case?

Comment: In this case it is *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two versions of [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)). The first one requires one index and the second one requires two indices. I've used the one which requires two indices, the first index (inclusive) is for start and the second index (exclusive) is for end.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter option: ");
        int option = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
        if (option == 4) {
            System.out.print("Enter phrase: ");
            String phrase = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter character: ");
            String letter = keyboard.nextLine();
            int index1 = phrase.indexOf(letter);
            int index2 = phrase.indexOf(letter, index1 + 1);
            System.out.println("The required word is '" + phrase.substring(index1 + 1, index2) + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter option: 4
Enter phrase: dog *is* sleeping
Enter character: *
The required word is 'is'
```

Comment: Is there a way with only the substring method and not the index?

Comment: There are two versions of [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)). The first one requires one index and the second one requires two indices.